# find_library() only finds the path of the first library name

Tags: cmake

I am referring the official [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_library.html) to use `find_library()` and my cmake version is 3.9.1.

In short, my `find_library()` only deals with the first library name and ignore the rest.

For example, when I do something like,

```
find_library (var NAMES libname1 libname2 PATHS libpath)
```

**var** will only get the full path-name of library **libname1** not the counterpart of **libname2**. Both the libraries are placed correctly in **libpath**. In fact, if I reverse the order as **NAMES libname2 libname1**, **var** will only get the full path-name of library **libname2**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find_library`command finds a library by trying the `NAMES` one after another. So the NAMES are synonyms for the library (e.g. libjpg libjpeg). After the first match it saves the path to the library in the variable `var`. You need to use two `find_library` calls to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: oh, I see. that is why the function is named as "find_library" not "find_libraries". thanks